# Ruby: graphical-user interface tk on linux ubuntu don't work

Tags: ruby, linux, user-interface, ubuntu, tk-toolkit

I tried installing the tk GUI for Ubuntu ruby
With the command:

```
gem install tk
```

But the command does not work.
What can I do?

Comment: Hi, can you past the command error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I ran into this same thing recently while porting the Princeton Standard library to ruby tk [standard_draw_tk](https://github.com/gregors/standard_draw_tk)

First make sure libaries are installed

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

Now you need to soft link the libaries

````
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tcl8.5/tclConfig.sh /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tk8.5/tkConfig.sh /usr/lib/tkConfig.sh
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcl8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/libtcl8.5.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.5.so.0 /usr/lib/libtk8.5.so.0```
````

Now you can install the tk gem on linux

```
gem install tk
```

The original [blog post](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-ruby-tk-bindings-gem-on-ubuntu/) where I found this information

Answer (score 2):

You can use options too.

```sh
gem install tk -- --with-tcltkversion=8.6 \
--with-tcl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tk-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--with-tcl-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--with-tk-include=/usr/include/tcl8.6 \
--enable-pthread
```

Answer (score 0):

Before install TK, you need Ruby dev (contains all the HEADERS):

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-all-dev
```

Comment: I have corretct my second post